# MS Word Table of Contents Line Break Issue

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, table-of-contents

I've got this bizarre problem.  In  a long, tightly formatted word doc (it's 350 book, with styles for everything)....
My Header1 styles chapter headers are, for example

```
0 Prologue
1 Chapter One
2 Chapter Two 
3 Chapter Three
```

When I generate the TOC it looks like this

```
0 Prologue        ...  1
1                ... 10 
Chapter One      ... 10 
2                ... 25 
Chapter Two      ... 25
3                ... 41
Chapter Three    ... 41
```

No matter what I do, the first WORD of the Chapter title  (except the very first one!) .. gets treated as a separate line.  No matter what I do.  Ive generated this many times ... I have examined the Header1 styles (for page break before etc).... and I have turned the "codes" on to see if there is any difference between the "prologue" heading and the others.  Nothing.

Any ideas??

Comment: 1. Is first word (the number) on the same line with "Chapter" in the text? 2. Do you use track changes? 3. What character is between the number and "Chapter" in the text? (for 0 and for 1)

Answer (score 0):

I looked at everything, especially the codes (when revealed).  Nothing.  But I realized that I was saving my documents to .doc format (the older) as opposed to .docx ...  the moment I started saving to .docx   the problem went away!